# Entity key type "one of", depend on other key value

Tags: typescript

How to describe in TypeScript this logic:

Say I have Entity "Quote". And Quote has a route:

```
interface RailLeg {
    set: number;
    of: string;
    unique: number;
    fields: number[];
}

export interface RailRoute {
  id: number;
  type: "RAIL";
  totalDeliveryTime: number;
  price: number;
  railLeg: RailLeg;
}

export interface CarRoute {
  id: number;
  type: "CAR";
  price: number;
  carLeg: CarLeg; 
}

interface CarLeg {
    car: string;
    properties: number;
}

// The most important part:
export type Route = RailRoute | CarRoute;

export interface Quote {
  id: number;
  route: Route; // Can be RailRoute or CarRoute
  price: number;
}


const handleQuote = (quote: Quote) => {
    // How better handle Type of Quote?
};
```

How should I properly handle that?
Is there a better way to organize code?

I'm fetching Company from API, how should I typesafe check for the vehicle type and use `vehicle` field in my code without `(as AirplaneProperties)` casting?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE. There should be no pseudocode, typos, undeclared or unimported types or values, missing syntax, etc.

Comment: You likely want to make `Vehicle` a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) as shown [in this TS Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N71xrW).  If that works for you I can write up an answer, once you update to make a [mre] showing your use cases and without typos and without undeclared types.  If it doesn't work for you, what am I missing?

Comment: thx @jcalz , here's [an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEp2AGwDIQObIDeAUMmcgM4RgBcyIArgLYBG0A3KeQPYx0VgooPJ3LIGIYAEcGEOo1YcuZGMAiYAJhXnM2UANoBdTgF9ixCAA8ADtyhhkoSLEQp0WVNwaQiXYBp1FKFFkMABPazlkACJUAEEASWxokLBuMDhMABF1YAA3aDCAFWAmKIU9EOshJEDKrigMHHw6d2aRYjMLGzsHJ2h4JGQAYTgoT28UEjJ-OqUycMi6aOG41BSuauBa+l155AQx3Dw6Uahj9mRO836XIbPj3zFDqH5BYRCyau5I+zVtXZBUzmKy2eyhCJuLw+AC8aCaEx8AB8RmNERBON0wX1wANXMgAIoMdJTPwBQH1MhQaFRdFVGrlPbBa7mBDcEACZAACzgIA0mAgRJJyDhAAoZCS6ELIABKEUAPie5AA9MrkAAJbgAd2QbDAzm5vP5KCKkOQvEJxMgAH5OuwgA)

Comment: Please put that example in your question as plaintext.  Did you look at the discriminated union code linked above or indeed the existing answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Live Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-3tWKqSHL3gJSPTmOJ94ZtqAA8AC0wHIAAqniQJQuAZbAA4OCgCgEgWIw6aZsglAQHy0CWFOi4Due772l+JQ-jwEq5Lek7TpiQA)

```
interface Vehicle {
  weight: number;
  size: number;
  type: string;
}

interface AirplaneProperties {
    airplaneAttr: any;
}

interface Airplane extends Vehicle {
  type: "airplane";
  properties: AirplaneProperties;
}

interface CarProperties {
    carAttr: any;
}

interface Car extends Vehicle {
  type: "car";
  properties: CarProperties;
}

type TVehicles = Car | Airplane;

interface Company {
  name: string
  vehicle: TVehicles
}

function run(company: Company) {
    // TypeScript know company.vehicle can be Airplane or Car. 
    // In this condition when company.vehicle.type === 'car', TS knows company.vehicle can only be Car
    // and it will assert the type within this block.
    if (company.vehicle.type === 'car') {
        company.vehicle.properties.carAttr
    } else {
        // Same as above, TS will assert company.vehicle as Airplane here.
        // company.vehicle.properties.carAttr // <-- Uncomment this line you will get error
        company.vehicle.properties.airplaneAttr
    }
}
```